# Laravel Multiple Timezones

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying build a database of user trips, which involves storing:

- FlightNumber
- DepartureAirport
- **DepartureTime**
- ArrivalAirport
- **ArrivalTime**

Note, that both the airports can be in different timezones. I need to work out the time difference, and number of days to this flight etc.

I am not sure how to approach this problem. Should I add more columns to store local date time, and UTC times?

Also, I have seen that Laravel has `dateTimeTz()` column type. However it doesn't seem to be storing any information about timezone?

Posts Table:

```
$table->dateTimeTz('newTime')->nullable();
```

Setting new time:

```
$p->newTime = \Carbon\Carbon::now('Asia/Kolkata')
=> Carbon\Carbon {#841
     +"date": "2017-03-28 16:23:33.490926",
     +"timezone_type": 3,
     +"timezone": "Asia/Kolkata",
   }

>>> $p
=> App\Post {#836
     id: 1,
     user_id: 1,
     title: "Et quaerat deserunt qui ullam voluptas.",
     body: "Aut eos id ut qui laborum. Tempore rerum ut quas deserunt voluptas optio.",
     slug: "et-quaerat-deserunt-qui-ullam-voluptas",
     newTime: "2017-03-28 16:23:33",
     created_at: "2017-03-28 10:51:36",
     updated_at: "2017-03-28 10:51:36",
   }
```

Comment: not a direct answer, but laravel uses the Carbon library so maybe look at those docs http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

is quite simple follow it:

- Store all timestamps in UTC (default in laravel config).
- The users can select their timezone and save it in the user table.
- Then you can use carbon to convert dates to their local time. (Carbon
  library, which is inside of Laravel already ).

**For example**, for a user who lives in different country like `Europe/London` or `Asia/Kolkata`

```
$something->created_at->timezone($user->timezone);
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to store date and time in UNIX timestamp (it's timezone independent). Then you can convert it to any timezone (depends on user location or airport timezone)